# Shall we clean up strikethrough content from answers?

Tags: discussion, revision-history, clean-up

Some answers get updated by:

- adding new content
- strikethroughing the obsolete content

Strikethrough sounds a bit primitive as we have a **revision system** for posts.

**Shall we remove or keep strikethrough content from answers?**

(I mean large strikethrough content of at least a complete sentence, not just a three-words short strikethrough content[*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1033581))

Here is an example where 80% of the content is obsolete: [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832084/1835379)
 ([revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9832084/revisions))

> [image: long answer with strikethrough]

Comment: Cleanup how? Automated? Manual? How do we determine what does, and what doesn't need to be removed?

Comment: @Cerbrus Manual human cleanup.

Comment: How do we determine what does, and what doesn't need to be removed? Or are you asking _"If we see this, should we remove it?"_?

Comment: @Cerbrus, I was tempted to remove all the strikethrough content from the given example. To remove or not to remove, that is the question.

Comment: A safe option is to ask the author to remove the text, if it's no longer necessary.

Comment: I think we s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶n̶'̶t̶ should clean it up.

Comment: Note that sometimes "strikethrough" is used as way to intentionally show that you have changed something. Could sometimes be used as a not so subtle sarcasm.

"That component will not work on <s>Internet Explorer</s> some browsers."

"We are working on the bug and it will get fixed <s>in 6-8 weeks</s> soon!"

Comment: What @Lundin said. Strikethrough has typographical significance, and is not merely or always an invitation to delete the struck-through text entirely.

Comment: What if someone is stuck on the old version? Shouldn't the old solution remain visible to them?

Comment: @user000001: If the struck-through text is intended to be useful in its own capacity, then the formatting should be removed.

Comment: In that specific case, maybe separate headers would be more helpful, like "From version 6 just do `this`. For version 5.3 upto 6, do `this this and this`. Etc..." But that's for this specific case. I don't think there is a need for a general rule, because I don't recall ever before having seen stricken out content that bothered me. So depends on multiple factors, and I don't think it would be useful or even doable to formulate a rulebook for dealing with this. Just trust your gut, clean-up a question if you're really certain, but always be careful that you don't delete too much.

Comment: That is quite a convoluted example. I suspect most cases of strikethrough text are small and deliberate *I'm leaving this in to draw attention to something earlier/wrong/incorrect that the reader needs to be aware of*. So no.

Comment: A simple [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/794551) can identify such answers (chose only to return highly upvoted ones, there are many, many such answers)

Comment: Adjusted. It now matches only answers with 100+ score, at least 4 characters struck through, a dot, and then at least another 4. That's 93 questions. Of course, I can match way more, and this is somewhat arbitrary, but if you want to edit you've gotta start somewhere.

Comment: @JanDoggen My impression from (my admittedly imperfect memory of) several years of using the site is that you're wrong on the facts; striking out entire paragraphs or even entire posts as a way of indicating that they've been revised is much more common than small strikethroughs meant to draw attention to particular important errors. I've seen the former maybe one or two dozen times, but don't recall ever seeing the latter.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Yeah, I think that folks coming from other sites/forums have gotten into the habit of simply using strikethrough to indicate that they're removing something from their post – because on those other sites, the post doesn't have a publicly viewable revision history. There's no such need to do that on SO/SE, but old habits die hard. (The same is true of explicitly noting edits in text with a note like "EDIT:".) If the info is still worth retaining in the answer, it's generally best to instead rewrite the answer to read as if it were always the best version of itself.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If someone is totally rewriting their answer like in your provided screenshot, then yes, that should be deleted. That's what the revision history is for. If they are using it for emphatic, contextual effect, like intentionally showing a word and then crossing it out and showing a <strike>better</strike> more appropriate phrase, that kind of strike-through should stay (assuming it's not fluff).

In this specific case, more stricken text than actual text is a little silly... and so it serves to highlight the problem pretty well, in my opinion. It's kind of like adding a tl;dr that is longer than the main post.

Comment: With such a large amount of editing, I think I'd prefer the revised version at the top, and then a horizontal line and a large disclaimer. It is (remotely) possible that the original answer can help out someone with, for example, an outdated system.

Comment: Strong disagreement due to the votes.  Most of them would have probably been on the strike-through version, and replacing what people upvoted with something totally different is misleading.

Comment: @Izkata Normally I would not agree; answerers have the right to edit their answer whenever they want; OP can always come by and remove the checkmark, and your vote is always unlocked if you cast one and then the answer is edited. However, in this case, I took a look at the history again and it turns out that it wasn't even the original answerer who made the huge edit. In that case, I agree that the answerer's original text should remain. Context is always key.

Comment: @Izkata As for the votes, if your curious, it has received 146 votes since the edit, vs 410 before the edit. That might seem like a big difference in favor of the original, but it has only been 10 months since that edit, whereas the previous revision (more or less) was around for 60 months. So it is actually earning twice as many upvotes per month since the edit than it earned per month prior.

Answer (score 37):

Again, my answer is: **Depends**. I'll explain why.

Learning from mistakes can be very helpful sometimes, especially when we don't always look at the answer's history.

For example, you might come across an answer that had an initial approach, which was then corrected (to a very similar one), but you were not aware of the original mistake. Now you understand the general idea, but you don't take the answer as-is, but prefer to have a "similar" solution, which is.. the older (wrong) approach. In such cases, I prefer to keep the strike to **highlight** the possible errors from the initial approach.

However, if it's a dead link, or a missing package that was moved, I don't see any reason why having a strikethrough would be helpful.

Comment: -1 for <strike>lack</strike>omission of <strike>pointless and snarky</strike>enlightening strikethroughs. (And no hand drawn circles)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov -̶1̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶k̶n̶o̶w̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶h̶o̶w̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶m̶e̶n̶t̶s̶.̶

Comment: @Maroun I think this is c̶h̶e̶a̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ f̲a̲b̲o̲u̲l̲o̲u̲s̲!

Comment: [I̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶l̶e̶a̶r̶n̶e̶d̶ ̶s̶o̶m̶e̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶](http://adamvarga.com/strike/)

Comment: You nerds. Now tell me how to strike through.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier we are not nerds, we're just smarter than you.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: unicode maybe (see hyperlink by Christian): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926669/strike-through-plain-text-with-unicode-characters

Answer (score 9):

I'm the original author of the answer in question.

I had chosen to use strikethrough because there were significant breaking changes between versions and the answer had been upvoted that high that I felt obliged to edit it in a way that shows the new solution but also keeping the old one for people that didn't upgrade yet.

Now I'm going to delete the old part as it is not relevant anymore.

For new situations like these I propose to use a headline on top indicating the current flow and a hr + headline indicating the old flow of doing things.

Comment: I'd advise against deleting the old information, and instead use the strategy noted in your final sentence: retain both the old and the new information, with clear demarcation about which is which and when each applies. Removal of old information should be reserved for cases where something has become so thoroughly obsolete that there's no longer any reasonable possibility of anybody finding it useful.

Comment: @JerryCoffin "Removal of old information should be reserved for cases where something has become so thoroughly obsolete that there's no longer any reasonable possibility of anybody finding it useful." yes this is now the case. Therefore I deleted the super-outdated parts.

Answer (score 9):

I think in this case (and probably many others) there was a legitimate need that the author was trying to meet, and simply deleting the stricken-out section(s) would do harm, not good to the answer.

I think in most cases it would be better to state the intent more directly and specifically though:

> #### After version Y
>
> [...]
>
> #### Versions X through Y
>
> [...]
>
> #### Before Version X
>
> [...]

As the original author implied, there may eventually come a point at which the older information simply becomes superfluous, but there's a fair amount of judgement needed in deciding when you've reached that point. The basic question at hand is whether there's any reasonable possibility of anybody finding that information useful any more. Given how recently I've helped people out with information about (for one example) a Control Data mainframe that was last manufactured in the 1980's (and seen others who cared about even older systems) I find it hard to be certain that such a point has been reached.

Given the (low) cost of storage, the primary reason to trim old information is to make it easier for the reader to find what's relevant. At least in most cases, that should lead one toward rearranging the content, so the most recent data is most visible (e.g., at the top of the answer) and older data (that's no longer as likely to be relevant) is made less intrusive (e.g., moved toward the bottom and eventually, perhaps, into a footnote where you can bracket it with `<sup>old data</sup>` to further de-emphasize it.

As long as it's clearly demarcated so a current user is unlikely to waste time reading outdated information, there's little or no value in removing the older information, and some value in retaining it.

#### Summary

The ideal is to make the information that's most likely to be useful as easily accessible as possible, while still making older information accessible when/if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting text is (at least to me) much easier than crossing it out (because you have to add [seldom used] strikethrough formatting).

So almost certainly the author *consciously chose* strikethrough over deletion. Almost certainly for a reason.

So changing strikethrough to deletion is equivalent to inferring/guessing said reason and deciding it is bad/unjustified and/or better served some other way.

Maybe this was obvious? ^_^'