# What to do (if anything) about a strike-through edit to an answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49021384/500276) yesterday. I think the situation is probably plain enough to most Meta users, so I won't really waste a lot of pixels setting up the scene.

I went through all of the suggested posts that came up when I entered the title to this question, and then I backtracked and ran a search on "strike-through edits". The overall consensus seems to be that strike-throughs are fine in some situations, not so much in others.

My impression is that -- by using the strike-through instead of just removing the text -- the user has "got his back up" over this, so I can't think of a way to comment further without it seeming accusatory or confrontational to the user. I don't have the chops to directly edit the answer, so I'm pretty sure that would end up being pointless. I'd be willing to state categorically that it doesn't need a custom mod flag, because I gather that those should be treated as analogous to calling the fire department.

So, the question is, does anything else even *need* to be done here, and if so, what?

Comment: Could be related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362695/shall-we-clean-up-strikethrough-content-from-answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing useful there.  There's no reason for it to be kept.  I've removed it.  Had you removed it, I'd honestly be pretty shocked if the edit would be rejected (by anyone other than the OP at least, there are certainly things that the review queues don't consistently get right, but removing greetings is something they're usually quite good at reviewing correctly).

To speak generally, the vast majority of uses of strikethrough fall into one of two camps, the information isn't useful, in which case, it should be deleted, not struck through, or it is useful, in which case it *probably* shouldn't be struck through.  In some cases the section of text needs a bit of editing to get just the useful information out of the section, but it's typically accomplished much better in ways other than strikethrough.

A common example of why people use strikethrough is someone made a mistake, and rather than removing the incorrect statement, they've struck it through to indicate that it's wrong.  If the author feels that it's useful for a reader to know that [some thing] isn't actually correct, it tends to be far more effective to simply edit the section to say, "keep in mind that [some thing] isn't a solution because of [reasons]".  I wouldn't say that it's *wrong* to use strikethrough in this way, just that it's usually a less effective way of presenting that information to a reader.

Comment: Yes, my only concern about editing it myself was that the OP would simply reject it out of hand, and I have zero interest in getting into an edit war.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield You could just flag the post for moderation attention at that point.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll remember that.