# What should we do for an answer which has strikethrough text for the entire content?

Tags: discussion, flags

I saw an answer which had content as shown in the below screenshot.
 **All the content except the last line of the answer was strikethrough text**.

If this should be flagged, should the flag be NAA or VLQ (if that matters)?
 Or should we just downvote it?

I referred to this related question as well: *[Shall we clean up strikethrough content from answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362695/shall-we-clean-up-strikethrough-content-from-answers)*.

[image: Answer screenshot]

Comment: Just downvote it.  It appears that the question may be the problem, so consider voting to close it too, if it is indeed lacking a MCVE.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you choose VLQ or NAA. They're handled in the same way, and they effectively mean the same thing: this answer is utterly unsalvageable and/or causing harm and therefore needs to be deleted by a moderator. That particular answer was self-deleted less than 1 minute after being flagged. The author realized they were wrong and deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

#### If I were in your situation, I'd flag it as *not an answer*.

The reason is because the conclusion of the answer is that they simply can't reproduce the problem.

If that's the case, the answerer should've flagged the question as *non-reproducible, or caused by a typo*.

Otherwise, what's the use of the  *non-reproducible, or caused by a typo* flag? 
The flag is there because people simply can't give an answer without being able to reproduce the problem.