# Should we ban strikethrough formatting?

Tags: discussion, formatting

I often see answers that contain significant amounts of struck-through text, <del>like this</del>.

I understand why the authors have done it; it's often to indicate where they've since updated their answer and left what was there for future reference.

However, it's nigh impossible for people with some neurological conditions to read text that has this strikethrough formatting.

I really think we should consider banning it in questions and answers.

Comment: I think it's a really useless style for a site like SO... but you really see it often? If you believe it's not useful and it's just noise in a post, you can always edit it out.

Comment: I find it quite useful for some things though, for example I often use it to emphasize (in a side note) that some variable is named badly or against conventions (Class names being written in `snake_case` instead of `PascalCase`, etc.)

Comment: huh... so it's near impossible to read text the author has deemed not worth reading. odd. (sounds like it's working as intended)

Comment: Possibly related: [Shall we clean up strikethrough content from answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362695/2821954) and its linked questions.

Comment: @Abdul Better just to explain things out than rely on a text-style that it's meant to make things harder to read. Frankly, even if I disagree on the "ban" stance, I find it hard to imagine many valid use cases for SO... if any at all.

Comment: I could [find only 11 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22%3Cdel%3E%22) where `<del>` is used. As far as I can see, `~~` is not supported. (10 after I edited one of them).

Comment: @yivi - That's probably because people edit it out when they see it... I do

Comment: @yivi that search seems to not consider `<s>` and also seems to ignore usage of `<pre><code>` otherwise it would have been much higher (Seen lots of posts of this style)

Comment: You can find plenty [with SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1420343).

Comment: Didn't know about `<s>`. Good thing users edit those out, although plenty of those still laying around. Sad. [Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1420360) update to search for either style. I imagine it's not impossible there are a few false positives, that are asking a question about the HTML elements.

Comment: Hmmm, you should probably stay away from CG&CC

Comment: [But what about questions *about* strike-throughs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107551/css-strikethrough-different-color-from-text)

Comment: @KevinB - If the author doesn't think it should be read then they should just delete it...

Comment: @Persistence I agree, to be clear. but banning it? i see no real reason to. Text that was made hard to read is hard to read. water is wet.

Comment: @Yatin - That's true... although you'd think we could perhaps generate a warning if the strikethrough covers more than one or two words?

Comment: @KevinB - The reason is accessibility and inclusivity. We don't want a situation where certain sections of our community can't access all of the information others can

Comment: we don't like all uppercase words, we don't ban them. we don't like code only answers, we don't ban them. we dont like all lowercase titles, we don't ban them. This is a copy-editing issue, you're not alone in finding strikethrough hard to read, it simply needs to be edited when used incorrectly.

Comment: To drag this mess back onto the topic at hand...

The other option would be to provide users with an accessibility option that would render the strikethrough in an easier to read fashion...

Something like ---strikethroughtext--- for instance (not how I actually suggest implementing it, just making clear what I mean)

Comment: @Persistence can you clarify how strikethrough makes posts less accessible?

Comment: It can be styled a few ways, color, thickness, and style, though i suspect giving it color or changing the style would do the opposite of what strikethrough is for. thickness is already 1.

Comment: @oleg - Given that having an underline that touches the lower part of dangling letters can severely affect dyslexic people... A full strikethrough definitely can https://www.bdadyslexia.org.uk/advice/employers/creating-a-dyslexia-friendly-workplace/dyslexia-friendly-style-guide

Comment: @Persistence I am unsure why you link to these guidelines - they do not mention anything about strike-through. It is generally exempt from WCAG as well (whereas bold and italics not so much). That being said, you may have a point because both `<del>` and `<s>` elements are not announced by default... Tough one

Answer (score 11):

There are many, many conceivable anti-patterns that could appear in posts on Stack Overflow. A veritable cornucopia of things can be done to/in posts that make them inaccessible and/or difficult to read.

Yet, we don't solve these problems by banning the use of all the things that might be misused. A post that is almost entirely written in boldface text is also very difficult to read—yet, bold can be useful in **small** quantities. So, too, can strikeout text.

> [I]t's often to indicate where they've since updated their answer and left what was there for future reference.

If so, that's almost certainly a misusage, and you are correct to remove it. Truly obsolete text doesn't need to be maintained inline in the post itself. This is tracked in the revision history, which is publicly accessible to anyone who might want to go and see how the post has changed over time, including reading old versions. (One wonders if these people have discovered source control systems, or if they still have every previous version of their code hanging around, commented out.)

But, again, editing solves this problem, which allows a human to exercise judgment, rather than outright banning the formatting style.

Answer (score -4):

An extremely rare neurological condition which affects a minimal number of people (if any at all) should not prevent the whole world from using a method of text formatting which is useful to convey meaning in a brief way.

As an asside, I have never heard of any neurological condition which prevents people from reading text which has a line through it. I am somewhat skeptical that such a condition exists, but if it does then someone who is a medical professional can feel free to correct me, or at least provide the name of such a condition, so that I and others can verify that it does in fact exist.