# Emphasized, inline code is displayed in cursive and thus unreadable on my machine

Tags: support, design, code-formatting, fonts

When a user uses emphasis on inline code, like so: *`the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, yes, THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG`*, it gets rendered in cursive on Windows 10, Chromium:

> [image: hisss]

I find that pretty unreadable. Why is this happening? How can I change this font rendering back to something more sensible and less curly?

Comment: It distracted me so much that I logged in again and posted this question, so there's that.

Comment: I currently can't think of a situation where this formatting would be ok on Stack Overflow. Emphasizing stuff or formatting code is fine on their own, but together? When would that be proper formatting?

Comment: @Tom why does your first sentence matter? I have encountered it, and it looks like shown above. What else do you suggest, correcting each instance we encounter, by removing the emphasis? On what basis?

Comment: Huh? Are you complaining that you have some font rendering issues on your computer? We have a site where we can help you get that resolved. It isn't Writing.SE. I don't know what in the world this has to do with a Q&A site about writing, or why inline code reminds you of that. I've never seen inline code in any professionally typeset work that I've ever read. I thought [we already had the discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408283) about why we shouldn't ban formatting just because it might be misused?

Comment: This is [your post on my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxbQl.png) when my CSS change is off.

Comment: @Cody I was taking some creative liberties with my writing, I am of course not asking for any markup to be banned. I've cleaned up the post, hopefully more clear now?

Comment: @Scratte so you're not on Windows 10 and Chromium, I presume?

Comment: Sorry. Only almost. The screen shot is from a Windows 10 and Opera. I just tried with chrome, and no difference. Trying Edge also didn't make the letters curly, like yours. When my CSS is on, it's this Answer to [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021/364269#364269) by Steven Penny

Comment: It's still a browser problem. Stack Overflow uses system fonts now; it was a fairly recent change.  So, if your fonts are rendering incorrectly or otherwise not to your liking, you need to reconfigure your system/browser settings, not request a site change.

Comment: I expect you can change to your preference in `chrome://settings/fonts`

Comment: @CodeCaster That's exactly what I said, yes. You're trying to fix an issue that doesn't exist. Or show a post which contains that formatting and where is correct for format it that way.

Comment: @Tom the issue definitely exists; I have found posts where this formatting is used, and I have provided a screenshot of how this is rendered. I am (definitely after the edit) not interested in discussing whether this formatting should be used; apparently people find it useful. I am explicitly talking about how it's being rendered; see my answer for the solution.

Comment: Like I said, that formatting style shouldn't be used anyway. Adding more formatting to inline code blocks neither makes it better or more readable, but can lead to issues like reported here. So what's your reason on keeping badly formatted code and change fonts instead? //Edit: ok then let's not discuss it any further and I'm looking forward to your next MSO post about how badly formatted text is rendered badly.

Comment: @Tom I am not here to convince you that people use emphasis to put emphasis onto text, and that that could apply to code as well (e.g.: "you use _`<em>`_ for emphasis, not `<i>`").

Comment: I am on windows 10, with chrome, and it doesn't do that for me. And either way, if someone uses italics like that, it should be edited out because that's an abuse of formatting.

Comment: Example of emphasis/code mix: quotes from manuals using emphasis to indicate parameters, like *`delim`* and *`array`* in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54561526/3266847).

Comment: @Cody thanks for the great edits, as usual!

Comment: Of course, no problem. But Ryan is more on top of Meta content these days than I am, it seems. You aren’t the first person to have been thrown by this.

Answer (score 9):

It turns out that the *`--ff-mono`* variable in the stacks.css resolves to this list of fonts:

> ui-monospace,"Cascadia Mono","Segoe UI Mono","Liberation Mono",Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,monospace;

And the [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) I have installed comes with the ["Cascadia Mono"](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code) font, which has cursive glyphs built in:

> [image: what the]

If you don't have this installed on your machine, then you won't be able to reproduce the problem. Time for me to uninstall some stuff.

(Oh, the irony. They [literally just modified the image from this post](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/commits/main/images/cascadia-code.png) to include "*`& Cursive`*".)

Comment: As an alternative to uninstalling you may find [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/8932) helpful.

Comment: @Bill thanks for the suggestion, but I've long given up on userscripts. I'm on too many different machines and browsers.

Comment: @CodeCaster be prepared for them to automatically reinstall when win 11 comes out :p

Comment: Hmm, cursive monospaced fonts: the next in a long line of things to be released from Microsoft that I wasn't aware I needed.